# Source of animation in Chrome tab between favicon and title?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I recently noticed this small animation appearing in Chrome tabs while testing a web app I'm working on. It appears and disappears while the page is loaded and I assume it indicates Ajax activity happening in the background. It happens quite randomly and now it's not happening again. I wondered if it is something to do with Chrome developer tools. Does anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in e.g. visual studio, the browser will constantly send a 'ping' ajax request.

Check your network tab in the browser development tools to see if similar network requests are being generated for you.